# Spring JPA ManyToOne relatsionship creates hashed foreign keys

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, hash, many-to-one

In my entity, I have defined a `@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` to my other entity. The relationship works fine.
Now I am using Postgre DB where I have created my tables and defined foreign keys between columns in my tables. In my DB, those keys work. When I use my Spring Boot application with it, Spring for some reason creates hashed foreign keys (`fk1sishw42l6qx85h5f3pckl6d0`) instead using the ones that I have created. At least I think, it uses those.

1. Why is that so?
2. How to avoid that?

Comment: you mean when you add data to the tables? Do you get the same hashed primary key for the entities that are referred to? How does your @Id field look like?

Comment: I don't necessarily have to add new data to my database, when this occurs. My @Id field looks like
`@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;`

And no, I get the hashed stuff only for foreign keys.

Comment: Spring doesnt create foreign keys, a JPA provider does. Spring is not a JPA provider. Perhaps mention which JPA provider you use and then use the log to see what is being created and add it to your question along with the JPA entities that it relates to

Comment: Sorry for late replay, I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution works, as it worked for me.

`@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="employeeID")
 @ForeignKey(name='your_existing_constraint_name')
 private employee employee;`